# Counting items based on multiple separators?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, split

I need to count the number of email addresses that a user inputs. Those addresses could be separated by any of the following:

- Comma followed by no space - `a@example.com,c@example.com.com`
- Comma followed by any number of spaces (ie. someone might have a comma follow by 3 spaces or just 1) - `a@example.com, c@example.com.com`
- Only white space - `a@example.com  c@example.com.com`
- New line

What's a good way to clean that up and reliably count the addresses?

I assume regular 'ole javascript could handle this, but for what it's worth I am using jQuery.

Comment: That's not how many e-mail addresses the string contains... That's just how many `whitespace|comma` the string contains. You could also count the number of `@`. That's also not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is just replace all commas with whitespaces, then, split your string based on blank spaces. No need for conditions.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/EA2xu/2/) a fiddle with an example on that.

Answer (score 2):

```
var emails = input.split(/[\s,]+/);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ej2Ka/)

Comment: +1 for the greedy pattern, splitting on all spaces will cause empty array elements, and therefore wrong count of email addresses

Comment: of course, this would have been my answer. I just added that explanation of the greedy match for info (in case the OP needs it, and why he shouldn't go for `/[\s,]/`, let alone `/ | ,|,/`

Comment: As empty spaces in the start and end are counting as emails, add this to trim the string before splitting: `input.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").split(/[\s,]+/);`

Answer (score 1):

```
var str="YOUR_STR",
    arr = [];
if( str.indexOf(',') >= 0 ) {
   // if comma found then replace all extra space and split with comma
   arr =  str.replace(/\s/g,'').split(',');
} else {
   // if comma not found
   arr = str.split(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var l = "a@example.com,c@example.com.com a@example.com, c@example.com.com a@example.com c@example.com.com";

var r = l.split(/ |, |,/);
```

Regular expressions make that fairly easy.

If there is change of more than one space, the regex can be changed a bit.

```
var r = l.split(/ +|, +|,/);
```